# Tradingview Charting Library: OnClick event on chart to get X,Y or Timestamp of the clicked candle/draw Ray/aVWAP

Tags: javascript, charts, tradingview-api

Is there support for drawing a Ray on TV chart of the SDK, and somehow communicate that to the hosting page's Javascript? Or as simple as OnClick to get the candle count or timestamp communicate to Javascript? If I get two points OnClick data, I can programatically draw the Ray anyway.

What about Anchored VWAPs? Can I draw specific pivots and somehow communciate that data to Javascript? I was thinking an OnClick event for a pivot could be enough and a label would be drawn on that pivot's High or Low.

Also, any chance the feeds from ByBit and Binance for their USDT pairs could be pulled into those charts? Or we need to manually load the data?

Comment: I'm seeking same answer.

Comment: any one found a solution for this?